# How to modify Meteor default mongodb configuration?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

When I run meteor, mongodb default address is 127.0.0.1:3001, how to modify it as: 0.0.0.0: 3001?
I can not find meteor default mongodb configuration file.

Comment: This question IS NOT duplicate. I've already asked of moderator intervention in order to remove "duplicate" mark.

Comment: are you talking about running meteor on development environment or production env?

Comment: @AnkurSoni Obviously, that's dev environment, because on production there is no such thing as running local mongodb server by meteor itself :)

Comment: i did not see `default` so was confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [source code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/tools/runners/run-mongo.js#L49), you can't do that, unfortunately.

The only option is to configure some proxy-server, `nginx` for example, that will proxy traffic between `0.0.0.0:3001` and `127.0.0.1:3001`.

**Update:** it's possible to do that now. `METEOR_MONGO_BIND_IP` env variable allows you to override IP address. ([diff](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/9606/files))

Comment: See like a major constraint.... can't believe this isn't configurable!?

Comment: @robjwilkins Well, actually, it's pretty reasonable constraint. Why would someone want to bind _locally started development `mongodb` server_ to external IPs? You can always configure&run your own `mongodb` server (binding it to `0.0.0.0`) and use it for your dev meteor projects.